# Querying a list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("570fc2381d4899be8a8ec9d9"),
"statuses" : [ 
    {
        "created_at" : "Wed Apr 13 09:56:39 +0000 2016",
        "id" : 7.20188946337153e+017,
        "id_str" : "720188946337153024",
        "text" : "RT @BCC_Assicura: #FormulaAuto la #polizza  #Auto e #Moto economica BccPordenonese - #BCC #Assicurazioni #Click2go"
    }, 
    {
        "created_at" : "Wed Apr 13 09:40:13 +0000 2016",
        "id" : 7.20184809658708e+017,
        "id_str" : "720184809658707970",
        "text" : "Auto e moto storiche, vademecum su assicurazione e bollo - \n#autostoriche #bollo #RCauto #ASI #FMI"
    }
]}
```

How do I query for all the records where the variable text contains the string "assicur"?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `r` a tag for this question? Seems like it should be removed.

Comment: Removed!
I need to translate the query from MongoDB to R later, i forgot to remove it while editing the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a regex;

```
> db.test.find({"statuses.text":{$regex: 'assicur'}})
```

That said, this will not be possible to index in mongodb, so it's probably best done along with other filters that cut the documents down to a small set before doing the string matching.

Comment: I'm new to Mongo, i understand what you say but i don't know where to start. Any help will be very useful!

Comment: @tia_0 If you want to match on a large amount of documents, you can't use the substring matching as your _only_ way of filtering. Regex works well with a few documents, but not in the millions. If you need text search there is - for example - free text support, however since you want a substring and not a word that's not really an option.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the hunch!
Now i just need to translate this to R and it will be perfect.